# How to access an account with the su-command?

Tags: mac-osx, accounts, su

**Problem:** to access an account in MacOS with the su-command, more [here](http://code.reddit.com/wiki/RedditStartToFinish#PostgreSQL). I can access my other accounts, but not the one created according to the intructions. The command does not change the user:

```
su postgres
```

**Question:** Why can I not access an account with the su-command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you get any sort of error? It could be that the account has an invalid shell (like /usr/bin/false) in which case it would switch to that user and immediately exit.

Try:

```
sudo -u postgres -H bash
```

Which will tell it to switch to the postgres user, set the HOME environment variable appropriately, and execute the bash shell

Comment: Great thanks! There was no error message, so I was very confused of the problem. Thank you again.

Comment: If there was no error message, are you sure it didn't work?

Comment: check /etc/passwd to see if the shell assigned to postgres is a valid one. check /etc/shells too.